# application block cache query

Tags: c#, caching, application-blocks

This is regarding MS Enterprise Application Block cache.

Is there a way to see what is inside cache in terms of keys? I am trying to find out if there is a way to query into cache object and find out which keys are stored in there. Then, once I have the keys, I could query the keys and see what is stored in them. Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own BackingStore, implementing from IBackingStore.
You then can do anything you want in there, for example, maintain a List with all the Keys with each Add/Remove issues to your own BackingStore. Example as follows:

```
public class MyBackingStore : IBackingStore
{
    public List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    public void Add(CacheItem newCacheItem)
    {
        keys.Add(newCacheItem.Key);
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        keys.Remove(key);
    }
}
```